# How data is transferred from html file to component.ts file

Tags: angular

I'm trying out angular2 with a simple form. Now when I used express, the value of the 'name' input for example, could be accessed in the server with req.body.name. But in Angular how is it actually assigned?

In clients.component.html file, in input, I have both [(ngModel)]="name", and "name" = "name" attribute. In clients.component.ts file, I created a name variable under ClientsComponent class:

```
...
  templateUrl: './clients.component.html'
...
export class ClientsComponent{
name;
...
onSubmit(){
  let newClient = {
    name: this.name
    }
  }
}
...
```

Now the code works perfectly, so there should be no syntax problem. I want to know how Angular recognize the value from html file. Is it because the ts file includes template URL, so every data from that template will come to this ts file? Also, was it the ngModel or the name attribute in the html that has to be equal to name variable in ts file, or do three of them have to be them same? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Angular uses a hierarchical structure for its component tree. This allows Angular to run change detection (detecting if the value used in a component has changed) from the current component on down. When you make a change to the input, the output variable (the `(ngModel)` part of the syntax) gets called which updates the variable `name` in the typescript/javascript.

See https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular-33f9ffff6f10